# I am something people love or hate, I change people's appearances and thoughts,

Tags: riddle

> I am something people love or hate.
>
> I change people's appearances and thoughts.
>
> If a person takes care of themselves I will go up even higher.
>
> To some people I will fool them. To others I am a mystery.
>
> Some people might want to try and hide me but I will show.
>
> No matter how hard people try I will never go down.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are

> Age

I am something people love or hate.

> People tend to love or hate their own age depending on how old they are.

I change peoples appearances and thoughts.

> People's appearances and thoughts change as they age.

If a person takes care of them self I will go up even higher.

> People live longer if they take care of themselves.

To some people I will fool them.To others I am a mystery.

> Some people do not look their age, some people do not know how old they are.

Some people might want to try and hide me but I will show.

> Some people try to hide their age using cosmetic methods but eventually it will show.

No matter how hard people try I will Never go down.

> Age only increases with time.